# Convert an image format from 32FC1 to 16UC1

Tags: numpy, opencv, scikit-image

I need to encode an image in 16UC1 format, but I receive the error:
*cv_bridge.core.CvBridgeError:encoding specified as 16UC1, but image has incompatible type 32FC1*

I tried to use skimage function `img_as_uint` but since my image values are not between -1 and 1 it doesn't work. i also tried to "normalize" my values by dividing all of them by the value obtained from `np.amax`, but using the skimage function only returns a blank image.

Is there a way of achieving this conversion?

This is the original [32FC1 image](https://www.filedropper.com/32fc1image)

Comment: Please provide some code so we can diagnose your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy you should be able to:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.normal(0, 1, (300, 300, 3)).astype(np.float32) # simulated image
uimg = img.astype(np.uint16)
```

You probably will first want to do some kind of normalization if it isn't already in an unsigned range.  Probably something like:

```
img_normalized = (img-img.min())/(img.max()-img.min())*256**2
```

But your normalization strategy will depend on what you want to accomplish.

---

Thanks for sharing an image.  I can visualize as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.load('32FC1_image.npz')
img = arr['arr_0']
img = np.squeeze(img) # this gets rid of the extra dimensions that are causing matplotlib to not recognize it as an image, the extra dimensions also may be causing your problems
img_normalized = (img-img.min())/(img.max()-img.min())*256**2
img_normalized = img_normalized.astype(np.uint16)
plt.imshow(img_normalized)
```

Try using the normalized 16 bit image.

Comment: Doing this returns a black image when using  `cv_bridge `

Comment: This is not surprising, it probably has to do with the normalization, probably means that there is a large value throwing for the colormap being applied.  Can you provide an example image?  You can save the original `32FC1` with `np.savez('myfile.npz', myimg)` then upload.

Comment: I have the .npz file but I dont know how to upload it

Comment: You could try this service and share the link:
https://www.filedropper.com/

Comment: I added the link

Comment: I can't open with `np.load('myfile.npz')`, are you able to load?

Comment: It is working know, just had to add `plt.show()` at the end